# Не устанавливается значение property при загрузке бинов из XML

Tags: java, spring

Есть класс загружающий XML, в котором описаны бины

```
public class BuilderInstanceContext {

    static DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();
    static XmlBeanDefinitionReader xml_bdr = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(factory);

    static {
        xml_bdr.setValidating(false);
        loadXmlBeanDefinitionReader(
                        BuilderInstanceContext.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("core_config.xml"));
    }

    public static void loadXmlBeanDefinitionReader(InputStream is) {
        System.out.println("loadBeanDefinitions : " + xml_bdr.loadBeanDefinitions(new InputStreamResource(is)));
    }

    public static DefaultListableBeanFactory getContext() {
        return factory;
    }
}
```

это работает, если в xml значения прописаны статически.

Если в описательном файле использую

```
<context:property-placeholder location="config/config.properties"/>
```

и бины описываю так

```
<bean id="data1" class="ru.firston.ms.develop_1.Data">
    <property name="value" value="${URL_TEMPLATE_SERVICE}"/>
</bean>
```

то при выполнении:

```
BuilderInstanceContext.loadXmlBeanDefinitionReader(TestLoadFile.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path_example));
Data data = (Data) BuilderInstanceContext.getContext().getBean("data1");
System.out.println(data.getValue());
```

в консоль получаю : `${URL_TEMPLATE_SERVICE}`

---

Enzo, спасибо. Со Spring пока все в новинку, попробовал следующее

```
public static void loadXmlBeanDefinitionReader(InputStream is, Resource...resources){       

    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer(); 

    ppc.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
    ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
    ppc.setLocations(resources);        
    ppc.postProcessBeanFactory(factory);

    System.out.println("loadBeanDefinitions : " + xml_bdr.loadBeanDefinitions(new InputStreamResource(is)));
}
```

но проблему это не решило видимо упустил, что то еще. параметры файла *.properties выводил, с ними все гуд. Пробовал добавлять через

```
ppc.setLocations(resources); ppc.setProperties(properties);
```

как понимаю  не хватает связывания `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` и `DefaultListableBeanFactory`, но в содержимом контекста объект класса `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` присутствует.

Comment: Вроде логично. Разве `XmlBeanDefinitionReader` должен за вас создавать `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, только потому что вы в файле написали `context:property-placeholder`? Его функция определения бинов читать. Вам его вручную надо создать, и сделать `postProcessBeanFactory()`. [Посмотрите](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/test/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyPlaceholderConfigurerTests.java) как в тестах.

Comment: А почему бы не создавать `ApplicationContext` по-человечески: `ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("core_config.xml", BuilderInstanceContext.class)`?

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример того что вы пытаетесь сделать. Не представляю зачем именно, но все-таки.

```
src
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── example
│   │       ├── app.properties
│   │       ├── config.xml
│   │       ├── Data.java
│   │       └── Main.java
```

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="data" class="example.Data">
        <property name="value" value="${URL_TEMPLATE_SERVICE}" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**app.properties**

```
URL_TEMPLATE_SERVICE = http:/localhost/templates
```

**Data.class**

```
public class Data {

    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**Main.class**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DefaultListableBeanFactory factory = new DefaultListableBeanFactory();

        XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader = new XmlBeanDefinitionReader(factory);
        reader.loadBeanDefinitions(new ClassPathResource("config.xml", Main.class));

        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer props = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        props.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("app.properties", Main.class));
        props.postProcessBeanFactory(factory);

        Data data = (Data) factory.getBean("data");
        System.out.println(data.getValue());
        // http:/localhost/templates
    }
}
```